# Unity Game Server not Running at Linux

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine, ubuntu, putty

I buildt my game server for Linux and checked headless mode. (I'm using UMMORPG)

and, preprared my linux server with this instructions:

https://noobtuts.com/unity/unet-server-hosting

So, when i enter command which start my game, there is not anything happens, only putty gets new line:

my game server is not running on ubuntu:

Thanks..

Comment: I don't think you gave enough informations for us to answer... There is a lot of configuration, programs, network issues where this problem may come from...

Comment: how can i get more debug logs in putty, i don't know, maybe crash reports or tell what happens on start?

Comment: Can you also edit your post to include picture in it. Not as a link... (Some people, including me, cannot access you site url)

Comment: You should add logs to the server's code

Comment: sorry for that, i added my images on the post

Comment: Which command do you use to start your server? Do you know `chmod` only give execution right to your program? It does not execute it!

Comment: I'm only logged in from putty and tried run the my file which named "server.x86". I was also tried 64 bit build "server.x86_64" file, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chmod` command only give *execution* rights to your executable. If you want to **run** it you should use:

```
./server.x86
```

As you can see your program is *not running* when you do `ps -A`

Comment: i will try it and make a feedback to you, thanks for your answer

Comment: @AlptuğrulKaradeli I think you missed from your tutorial the 2nd line after: `chmod +x ./game.x*` there is `./game.x86_64` :)

Comment: Okey, i'm try the server in my game and it's succesfully connect to server. Thanks for your answers. :) :)

Comment: @AlptuğrulKaradeli Glad it helped :)